# RAD 9.1 parseint(String) not defined for SimpleDeserializer

Tags: java, methods, websphere, ibm-rad

I work with RAD 9.1 and java 1.6.

I have the following instruction

```
((MensajeIndemnizacion)value).setStatus(com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.parseint(strValue))
```

When I build the project, I get the error:

```
Method parseint(String) is not defined for type SimpleDeserializer
```

com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer doesn't have the method parseint.

How do can I fix this error?

**EDITED**

Screen RAD

[image]

**EDITED**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Integer.parseInt(String)` to convert a String to an Integer.

Comment: I attach a screen with my code. This class doesn't have methods. I edit the question

Comment: Try edited answer. Are there any method suggestions for `new SimpleDeserializer().`?

Comment: Attach a screen with the suggestions. Edited the question

Comment: Import the first one and check your method.